# How to broadcast data from MySQL and use it in streaming batches?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

// How do I get attributes from MYSQL DB during each streaming batch and broadcast it.

```
val sc = new SparkContext(sparkConf)
val ssc = new StreamingContext (sc, Seconds(streamingBatchSizeinSeconds))
val eventDStream=getDataFromKafka(ssc)
val eventDtreamFiltered=eventFilter(eventDStream,eventType)
```

Comment: Please note that my first reaction was to consider your question as low quality and _only_ because I had time I thought _"let's give this person a chance to improve"_ and...answered.

Answer (score 1):

Whatever you do in `getDataFromKafka` and `eventFilter` I think you get a `DStream` to work with. That's how your future computations are described by and every batch interval you have a `RDD` to work with.

The answer to your question greatly depends on what exactly you want to do exactly, but let's *assume* that you're done with this stream processing of Kafka records and you want to do *something* with them.

If `foreach` were acceptable, you could do the following:

```
// I use Spark 2.x here

// Read attributes from MySQL
val myAttrs = spark.read.jdbc([mysql-url-here]).collect

// Broadcast the attributes so they're available on executors
val attrs = sc.broadcast(myAttrs) // do it once OR move it as part of foreach below

eventDtreamFiltered.foreach { rdd =>
  // for each RDD reach out to attrs broadcast
  val _attrs = attrs.get

  // do something here with the rdd and _attrs
}
```

*I tyle!*